# Update class of parent element by change on ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to do like..,

If *ng-model* is not equal to blank then update the class of  which is just written above of this *ng-model*.

I have overridden the *ngModel* directive by this. I am also able to get change on it by applying $watch to that *ngModel*. But I have stuck at this, how to get that  position.

I can try *ng-class* to change that but I want something that can update the globally.

```
app.directive('ngModel', function($http ,$parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("model", function() {
                console.log(scope.model);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is example HTML. Here I am trying to change that span class by detecting change on its model.

```
<span class="input">
    <input class="input__field" ng-model="example" required="" type="text">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `element` argument of the `link` function like below

```
app.directive('ngModel', function($http ,$parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch("model", function() {
                element.parent()[0].className='Your class name'
                console.log(scope.model);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses [$viewChangeListeners](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) on the model controller:

```
angular.module('scopePropertiesModule', [])
  .directive('ngModel', function($timeout){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      compile: function(){
        return {
            pre:function(scope, $elem){

            $elem.wrap("<div class='o-input'></div>")
              .parent();

          },
          post:function(scope, $elem, attrs, ctrl){

            var checkValid = function(e){
                $timeout(function(){

                if(ctrl.$valid){
                  $elem.parent().addClass('valid');
                }else{
                  $elem.parent().removeClass('valid');
                }

              });
            };

            ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(checkValid);
            checkValid();

          }

        }

      },
            scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
      }
  }});
```

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/robstarbuck/t7ufn3u1/

The use of $timeout is necessary.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, i added the outer input's outer div in the directive rather than including it in the markup.